# NameSplit = Source.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(Seperator)})

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, split, char

Can anyone help me, Im new to VB and are using code to log temperatures via USART from a microcontroller. I have this function to get my string in the CSV format.
I have difficulty understanding the line : `NameSplit = Source.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(Seperator)})`

```
Public Class Form1
    'PARSE THE TEXT IN THE FILE PER "CSV" STYLE ==> (Items per Record)
    Public Function Field(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Seperator As String, ByVal Index As Integer) As String
        Dim NameSplit As String()        'Declare nuwe variable waarin
        NameSplit = Source.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(Seperator)})    'Vind enige karakter en gryp hom, soek dan n komma wat die sepearotr is en split
        If Index - 1 < 0 Then
            Field = "Index out of range"
        Else
            Field = NameSplit(Index - 1)
        End If
    End Function
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's creating a single element `Char` array with the passed in `Seperator` (probably a comma), and using it as an argument to the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) function, which returns multiple strings having split it on the separator(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.Split from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

*Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array.*

In your case you are using the overload: `Split(Char())`: splitting the string using a character array.

But your code is converting the string argument `Separator` into a character array. Note that this actually only converts the first character in the string to a character array of 1 element.

Also note the square brackets are not required around `[Char]` and so in your case this is functionally equivalent to:

```
NameSplit = Source.Split(CChar(Seperator))
```